# Block matrixes and invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Let $À : L \to L, 
L = L_1 + L_2$.
In my book it says if space $L$ is equal to the direct sum of $2$ invariant subspaces of $L$ then matrix $A$ (representation of linear operator $À$) can be divided into blocks like this \begin{bmatrix}A_1&0\\0&A_2\end{bmatrix}
Where $A_1$ is restriction of $A$ on subspace $L_1$ and $A_2$ is that on $L_2$.
So why couldn't we do the same if $L_1,L_2$ were just non invariant subspaces? In the proof, it says if $L_1$ is invariant then restriction of $À$ on $L_1$ will also be linear couldn't we say the same if $L_1$ were just a subspace?

Comment: *"if L space is equal to sum of 2 invariant subspaces... will be divided into blocks like this"* $\begin{bmatrix}A_1&0\\0&A_2\end{bmatrix}$... isn't acutally true.  It could be e.g. $ \begin{bmatrix}A_1&B\\0&A_2\end{bmatrix}$ .  Now if L is equal to the **direct sum** of two invariant subspaces then that does imply the block diagonal structures $\begin{bmatrix}A_1&0\\0&A_2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: yeah forgot to mention direct sum. But why it needs to be invariant subspace?

Comment: what does *"why it needs to be [T] invariant subspace?"* mean? There's two directions here-- (i) the block diagonal structure implies direct sum of two T invariant subspaces, and (ii) direct sum of two T invariant subspaces implies block diagonal structure (with appropriate basis chosen).  Arbitrary subspaces are closed under linear combinations but not necessarily under application of a linear operator, that's why T-invariance is introduced as a concept.  My sense is you need to carefully write out the definitions and try to prove (i) and (ii).

Comment: The theorem is that direct sum of two invariant subspaces implies block diagonal structure so I wanted to understand why invariant is so essential. So arbitrary subspace isn't closed under linear operator? But why? Let L be subspace of V if we take x, y from L then A(x+y) = Ax +Ay as A was linear of V and x,y are also from V same goes for A(ax)=aAx in my opinion.